# How to restore a Paste Shortcut CTRL+V

Tags: keyboard, copy, shortcut-keys, paste

I installed an clipboard app and selected <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for it. Now, the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does not work even if uninstall the app. How restore a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut?

Comment: can you share a link to clipboard app please.. and what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: OP [uses elementary OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118969/how-to-restore-a-paste-shortcut-ctrlv#comment1849015_1118974)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to " Settings--> Keyboard-->Reset All "
(it'l reset all your shortcut keys)

worked for me (ubuntu 18.04)

or you can find that specific key bindings and change according to your use.

Comment: sorry, my distro is elementary, not have this option, i use restore in about settings

Comment: solved in elementary on reset in settings